# Command pattern: how can I do continuous actions? (e.g. moving an object)

Tags: c++, command-pattern

Suppose that I'm making a program where user can draw and then move shapes around. `MoveCommand` then can look something like this:

```
class MoveCommand {
public:
    MoveCommand(Shape& shape, const Vector2f& offset) :
            shape(shape), offset(offset)
    { }

    void execute() {
        shape.move(offset);
    } 

    void undo() {
        shape.move(-offset);
    }
private:
    Shape& shape;
    Vector2f offset;
};
```

This works well, but how can I display preview of movement (when user holds mouse button) and then only store final offset on mouse button release?

Should `ShapeEditor` class move the shape and then create `MoveCommand` on button release? What if the code of `execute()` is not trivial? How can I avoid code duplication in `ShapeEditor` and `MoveCommand`?

Comment: hi , i know you , you are writing a game topdown for 4 years or so? with an editor inside it lol! XD.............shape.move(-offset); will this really work? you dont get exactly same offset from previous frame.

Comment: @LorenceHernandez yeah, that's me! :D
Suppose that your object is at (20, 30) and offset is (10, 20). After moving the object, it's new position is (30, 50). If I move it by (-10, -20) now, I'll get (20,30) - the position it was in before the command execution.

Comment: okay i thought you were using delta time and get like 0.424 , 0.399, 0.524.. so with those  values undo will be imperfect. theres a book called game programming patterns it explains command pattern very well i think? because i havent finished reading it

Comment: hi, would you mind giving me anything that i can contact you? maybe skype or any messenger app or anything, i just want to ask some things about a game i will work on a college project thanks.

Comment: @LorenceHernandez, write me an e-mail: eliasdaler@yandex.ru

Comment: hi, thanks for that !

Comment: Hi, I just emailed you yesterday through my gmail, read it when you are free thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This works well, but how can I display preview of movement (when user holds mouse button) and then only store final offset on mouse button release?

If I understand you correctly, you want to make the whole movement un-doable / re-doable as a single operation, while animating each individual micro-movement when it's done interactively the first time.

One way to do it is what you suggest yourself, that is recording the undo / redo command only when the movement is complete. As you point out, that leads to some code duplication. In practice that's not a problem, as you can always factor that common code out.

Another way is to create a MoveCommand for every micro-movement and then implement command merging as part of your undo / redo stack. See how it's [done in Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qundocommand.html#mergeWith).

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for.